# xslt select attribute from variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm with xslt, and have run into a problem(i'm new to this). I have some xml in a variable called `gmlMember`, and a variable containing a name called `var_FeatureClassName` which contains "BES_VANDLOEB"

The xml looks like this (contained in gmlMember):

```
<dmp:BES_VANDLOEB gml:id="BES_VANDLOEB.52626" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:dmp="https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer">
   <dmp:OBJECTID>94808</dmp:OBJECTID>
   <dmp:Temakode>2014</dmp:Temakode>
   <dmp:Temanavn>Beskyttede vandløb</dmp:Temanavn>
   <dmp:Objekt_id>{D2BDC519-5374-11E2-B629-00155D01E765}</dmp:Objekt_id>
   <dmp:Version_id>{F744FAB7-04A4-4DAE-8A03-A765D86CEA52}</dmp:Version_id>
   <dmp:Systid_fra>2006-12-31T23:59:00</dmp:Systid_fra>
   <dmp:Oprettet>2006-12-31T23:59:00</dmp:Oprettet>
</dmp:BES_VANDLOEB>
```

I need to get gml:id="BES_VANDLOEB.52626"

I have tried various things like the following:

```
  <xsl:variable name="gmlId">
    <xsl:value-of select="$gmlMember/$var_FeatureClassName/@gml:id"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

That doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can get it?

Comment: Don't tell us something doesn't work. Tell us how it fails. The failure symptoms are the starting point for any diagnostic process.

Comment: Well. my variable is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly:

Here xslt example:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMer/3

Xslt code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:dmp="https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="gmlMember" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="var_FeatureClassName" select="'dmp:BES_VANDLOEB'" />
        <xsl:variable name="gmlId">
            <xsl:value-of select="$gmlMember//*[name()=$var_FeatureClassName]/@gml:id"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="$gmlId"/>
        </id>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Xml input:

```
<root>
    <dmp:BES_VANDLOEB gml:id="BES_VANDLOEB.52626" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:dmp="https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer">
        <dmp:OBJECTID>94808</dmp:OBJECTID>
        <dmp:Temakode>2014</dmp:Temakode>
        <dmp:Temanavn>Beskyttede vandløb</dmp:Temanavn>
        <dmp:Objekt_id>{D2BDC519-5374-11E2-B629-00155D01E765}</dmp:Objekt_id>
        <dmp:Version_id>{F744FAB7-04A4-4DAE-8A03-A765D86CEA52}</dmp:Version_id>
        <dmp:Systid_fra>2006-12-31T23:59:00</dmp:Systid_fra>
        <dmp:Oprettet>2006-12-31T23:59:00</dmp:Oprettet>
    </dmp:BES_VANDLOEB>
    <dmp:SOME_VANDLOEB gml:id="BES2126" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:dmp="https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer">
        <dmp:OBJECTID>94808</dmp:OBJECTID>
        <dmp:Temakode>2014</dmp:Temakode>
        <dmp:Temanavn>Beskyttede vandløb</dmp:Temanavn>
        <dmp:Objekt_id>{D2BDC519-5374-11E2-B629-00155D01E765}</dmp:Objekt_id>
        <dmp:Version_id>{F744FAB7-04A4-4DAE-8A03-A765D86CEA52}</dmp:Version_id>
        <dmp:Systid_fra>2006-12-31T23:59:00</dmp:Systid_fra>
        <dmp:Oprettet>2006-12-31T23:59:00</dmp:Oprettet>
    </dmp:SOME_VANDLOEB>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<id xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:dmp="https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer">BES_VANDLOEB.52626</id>
```

Comment: Hmm. My var_FeatureClassName doesn't contain "dmp", only "BES_VANDLOEB". Maybe i could add dmp, i don't know.

Comment: Then you can use `local-name()` instead of `name()`. This returns the element name without namespace.

Comment: I see that your example works. Mine however is empty. Odd

Comment: I need more information. Is there a link to the example?

Comment: I figured out what it was. my dmp:BES_VANDLOEB is my root element. So i did $gmlMember[name()=$var_FeatureClassName]/@gml:id, and now I have the value.

Answer (score 3):

A variable in XPath represents a value, not a fragment of an expression (it's not a macro language). So `$a/$b` means "for each value in `$a` return the value of `$b`". So if `$a` contains 6 nodes, and `$b` contains the string 'className', then the result will be a sequence containing 6 occurrences of the string 'className'. If you intended the result to be equivalent to the result of the expression `$a/className`, then you should have written `$a/*[name()='className']` (or some refinement of that to take namespaces into account).

(This explanation applies to XSLT 2.0/3.0. In XSLT 1.0, writing `$a/$b` is a static error, it's not a valid expression. That's why I asked you to tell us how it failed.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I got it to work with the example given. But now I know how it works.